# Can Datomic dev-local be installed on windows?

Tags: windows, installation, clojure, datomic

I'm trying to install Datomic on a Windows 10 computer, following the [official instructions](https://docs.datomic.com/cloud/dev-local.html).

I [downloaded](https://cognitect.com/dev-tools) and unzipped the dev tools as instructed.

I cannot, however, run the install script because it is a bash script.

I opened the script and discovered it requires maven, so I installed maven and tried to run the commands manually.

```
echo 'Installing: com.cognitect/rebl {:mvn/version "0.9.242"}'
mvn -q org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.0.0-M1:install-file -Dfile=rebl-0.9.242/rebl-0.9.242.jar
echo 'Installing: com.datomic/dev-local {:mvn/version "0.9.232"}'
mvn -q org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.0.0-M1:install-file -Dfile=dev-local-0.9.232/dev-local-0.9.232.jar
```

At first this errored with

> The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory

So I figured out how to create a maven pom.xml.

Then it errors

```
[ERROR] The specified file 'C:\workspaces\clj-recipe\rebl-0' not exists
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.0.0-M1:install-file (default-cli) on project clj-recipe: The specified file 'C:\workspaces\clj-recipe\rebl-0' not exists
```

Is dev-local not intended for windows?

### Update

I did get the maven scripts to run. I created my own install.ps1 in the dev tool directory, which kept paths the same, and quoted the file paths.

```
# expects to be run from the project (pom.xml) directory, but in a script file in the same directory as the original install script

echo 'Installing: com.cognitect/rebl {:mvn/version "0.9.242"}'
mvn -q org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.0.0-M1:install-file -Dfile="rebl-0.9.242/rebl-0.9.242.jar"
echo 'Installing: com.datomic/dev-local {:mvn/version "0.9.232"}'
mvn -q org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.0.0-M1:install-file -Dfile="dev-local-0.9.232/dev-local-0.9.232.jar"
```

I still can't get dev-local to run though. There appears to be no changes to the pom.xml.
I start up a repl for the current lein project and run

```clj
(require '[datomic.client.api :as d])
(def client (d/client {:server-type :dev-local
                       :system "dev"}))
```

Getting the error `No such namespace: d`.

My guess is that I don't understand how deps.edn works... Right now I have a single deps.edn under `C:/Users/[username here]/documents/.clojure/deps.edn`

```clj
{
:mvn/repos {"cognitect-dev-tools"
             {:url "https://dev-tools.cognitect.com/maven/releases/"}}

:deps
{com.datomic/dev-local {:mvn/version "0.9.225"}}
}
```

Comment: While you may get an answer here, https://ask.datomic.com is at least one official support channel for Datomic.

Comment: The best way to run on Windows is to install Git Bash.  Even if you don't need the Git part, it gives you a nice Linux & Bash emulation on Windows:  https://git-scm.com/downloads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were two key issues here

1. The install script is not necessary with leiningen (and is not written for windows)

   - If you want to use a maven-based approach, then use the install script. Be warned that you need maven installed.
   - The install script can be tweaked for windows by changing as shown above (quote paths, remove the cd, make it a ps1 file)
2. The deps.edn, maven, and leiningen paths are not compatible. I must configure the dependency using leiningen to use it in my lein-based project

Configuring for lein is fairly simple

- add a repositories configuration section
- add a package dependency

```clj
(defproject ;;...
  :dependencies [
                 ;;...
                 [com.datomic/dev-local "0.9.225"]
                 ]
  :repositories [
                 ["cognitect-dev-tools" {:url      "https://dev-tools.cognitect.com/maven/releases/"
                                         :username :env/datomic_username
                                         :password :env/datomic_password}]]
;;...  
)
```

Note that the credentials have to be supplied to the lein project. This can be done with

- environment variables as shown above (specify the name as `:env/var-name-here`)
- or [using an encrypted password field](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/DEPLOY.md#gpg)
- [or use a profile](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/DEPLOY.md#full-disk-encryption)